# JMeter Error when I try to save a test plan file

Tags: jmeter

I have the following error when I tryed to save my test plan in JMeter: Couldn´t save to file (Acess Denyed)
¿Can anyone help me?

The log trace is this one:

```
 ERROR o.a.j.g.a.Save: Failed to backup file : C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Sisteplant\LoadTests\TestDefinitions\HandlingUnitStateChangeSimulation.jmx
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Sisteplant\LoadTests\JMeter\backups\HandlingUnitStateChangeSimulation-000001.jmx (Acceso 
denegado)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.doCopyFile(FileUtils.java:1142) ~[commons-io-2.5.jar:2.5]
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1088) ~[commons-io-2.5.jar:2.5]
at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:1040) ~[commons-io-2.5.jar:2.5]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Save.createBackupFile(Save.java:378) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 
r1790748]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Save.doAction(Save.java:209) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:74) ~ 
[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.lambda$actionPerformed$0(ActionRouter.java:59) ~ 
[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_191]
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_191]
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_191]
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_191]
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_191]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) 
[?:1.8.0_191]
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_191]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_191]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_191]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_191]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_191]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_191]
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_191]
```

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your user doesn't have write permissions for the `C:\Program Files (x86)` folder therefore you're getting this error.

Choose different location (you definitely have write access to your home folder)

Another option is to [run JMeter as administrator](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/run-a-command-as-administrator-from-the-windows-vista-run-box/), this way you get rid of `WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0` error as well which unlock some customisation persistence.

---

Also be informed that according to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.3](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-3-released-td5728863.html) (or whatever is the latest stable JMeter version which is available at [JMeter Downloads](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) on next available opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

not being on Java8 was the problem for me.
Install Java 8 and it will run fine.

Answer (score -1):

Try the *following*:

- Open `JMeter` -> `Options` -> `Look and Feel` -> Select any other theme other than `Darcula`.
- Restart `JMeter`,
- Create test plan and
- try to save.

Save should work.